# Configure FreeBSD pf firewall (non GUI)

Tags: terminal, freebsd, pf

I am running Mac OS X 10.10, but my research has led me to the understanding that the particular flavor of pf was ported from FreeBSD. I have tried the popular GUI software (IceFloor) but it is a bit convoluted, so If it must be convoluted, I'd rather learn it the power user way. I haven't been able to find any helpful tutorials that break it down to a beginner level. I've looked at examples, but I don't understand them since I don't know what I am looking at. I am wanting to make multiple configuration profiles for different situations (home, school, coffee shop, etc). Would someone willing to break it down and explain it such as: syntax, what each thing is doing, why it is meaningful?

Comment: The Book of PF by Peter N. M. Hansteen is the best that you will get(not counting the man pages by the openBSD team(the pf developers)).

Comment: Oh by the way, PF firewall has 3 syntax for 3 release, When you read a book or manual or tutorial and test their rules, may be get some syntax error.